# Does Circuit Superstars support splitscreen with two (identical) controllers?

Tags: pc, controllers, circuit-superstars

Is it possible to play [Circuit Superstars](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1097130/Circuit_Superstars/) in split screen (i.e. local multiplayer) with two (identical) controllers?

I know that the game's Steam page mentions both *Split Screen* and *Full controller support*, but I still wanted to ask here, to be sure. Especially after being frustrated with [F1 2020](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1080110/F1_2020/), which also mentioned both *Split Screen* and *Full controller support*, yet doesn't support split screen with two controllers (one of the players must use the keyboard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It does.

[According to one of the developers](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1097130/discussions/0/5836080604446031461/) (May 2021):

> You can play local multiplayer with up to 4 others **as long as each of you have a controller** (this is being looked into to allow one player access to the keyboard).

To the question "*So I can easily plug in a gamepad and the game will detect it as another controller and we can play splitscreen?*", they answered:

> You will need to plug in at least 2 controllers but otherwise, yes.

Later on clarified to mean:

> **You will need a gamepad for each player in local multiplayer**, but as I mentioned before, the team at OFG are working on fixing that (I'm part of the Publishing team Square Enix Collective).

This is corroborated [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1097130/discussions/0/5221353200095305563/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I've just purchased it and tested, it does work indeed, with two identical controllers.